# How to read search keyword from excel sheet one by one. can any1 help me how to do it using java webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium

I have a search engine in my application. i have created an excel sheet
with 100 keywords in a column.
Each keyword has to be read from excel sheet one by one. can any1 help me
how to do it using selenium web driver??

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged the question with **java**, I think you are using the Java language binding.
Just download and add to your project the [Apache POI library](http://poi.apache.org/) and then you can read the Excel input file.
You can iterate all the rows in the first column and store them in an `ArrayList<String>` or any other data structure that fits your needs before starting the test. [Here's a quick guide on reading a spreadsheet file](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html).

The code you need is here:
1. [open the file as a Workbook](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#TextExtraction)
2. [get the cell contents](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents)

Another options could be saving your values in a CSV file (easier coding), but I understand that Excel is so commonly used that it comes very handy to let everyone create input files for data-driven tests.